# Windows 10 login only accepting e-mail not local domain user

Tags: windows-10, windows-domain, login-screen

This is a strange one I can't seem to figure out. This is my PC running Windows 10 Education edition.

I connected to my university's Azure AD last year, and created a local profile from the student e-mail address.

During that time I had logged into a second account (for personal use i.e. gaming) which is linked to a microsoft account.

Today I wanted to create a local account to personalise another desktop for a specific type of work.

Upon creation Trying to switch that user will show a wrong username / password.
Attempting to type "\username" results in the error "You can't sign in with a user ID in this format. Try using your email address instead.

I would remove myself from the AzureAD, however my main account is tied into it.

### Things I've tried:

- Filtering out any changed settings in Group policy that would effect it
- Viewing Regedit changes
- Advanced User settings to change the account to local

Comment: When you type your username are you specify it's a username that exists on the machine and not on the domain?

Comment: I've created the account as a local user. To clarify I haven't joined the university domain, however am connected to their Azure AD. The computer is still on the default 'workgroup'. Is ther another way I should be trying to access the account?

Comment: When you attempt to log into the account.  What domain does it indicate?  You should specify the machine's name then the username (i.e.`Computer1\Username`)

Comment: That was the answer! Don't know why I didn't think of that sooner. "(i.e.ComputerName\Username)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Today I wanted to create a local account to personalise another desktop for a specific type of work.
>
> Upon creation Trying to switch that user will show a wrong username / password. Attempting to type "\username" results in the error "You can't sign in with a user ID in this format. Try using your email address instead.

You need to log into the local account by switching the to the local machine instead of trying to log into the domain.

You can do this by using: **ComputerName\Username**

Comment: .\Username should work too. In the event you have forgotten the name of your computer.